# Entity Framework use foreign key names for navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How can we get the templating script when using DB first approach in EF 6 to use the foreign key names to generate the entity (navigational) property names rather than the format of Entity1, Entity2 etc?

An example where this is an issue is if you have a table that has columns like createdby, updayedby etc and these have foreign keys to a user table EF will use the alphabetical order of the foreign keys to generate the properties of the table entity and you end up with User, User1 as properties. This becomes a big issue when you later add a new FK to the user table with a name that causes User1 not to be the updatedby user anymore because the new FK appears above the updatedby FK of that generated User1 before!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know there was some (tricky) way to do this...getting your hands on the templates that drive the EDMX creation. Maybe someone will be able to point you to that. But also keep in mind 3rd party tools. LLBLGen Pro can do this easily. Here is the relevant documentation: https://www.llblgen.com/Documentation/5.3/Designer/Functionality%20Reference/ProjectSettings.htm#name-construction-name-patterns

Answer (score 1):

For code first from database, you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp which will add the tt templates used to your project.

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ, is there anything for DB first? I'll look at those anyways there might be some clues in there.

Comment: That IS for Database First (but no EDMX)

Comment: Oops meant DB first with EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the generated EDMX file/diagram and rename the navigation property to a name which fits its role. So instead of `User1` and `User2` you can simply rename them to `UpdatedByUser` and `CreatedByUser`.

Comment: issue here is that the file is dynamic so it regenerated each time... and I have many properties with this issue